# No Entity Framework provider found error after installing lastest Nuget package

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I just upgraded EF to 6.1.3 and I'm getting the error:

`No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.`

Everything was working fine with version 6.1.2.

I installed EF through the `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution` and also directly using the PM console.

I also have a reference to the latest `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` in the projects where I'm using EF.

EF is in my `Model` project and the app.config looks like this:

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
```

The MVC project has the actual connection strings (in a separate file outide web.config) and they are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <connectionStrings>
  <clear/>
  <add name="Blank" connectionString="data source=myserver;initial catalog=mydb;user id=***;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=MyApp" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Should I reinstall the previous version? What is the solution for this problem?

**EDIT**

The problem was that the main MVC project was referencing `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` from version 6.1.2. This reference was removed and the DLL from version 6.1.3 is now being referenced. The app now works fine.

However, is there an alternative to referencing this DLL if it's not needed in the main project?

Comment: try nugget package manager console with command : PM> Install-Package EntityFramework

Comment: What do the connection strings and entity framework sections of your config file contain? (And how is the latter section registered?). Remember to obscure any sensitive information.

Comment: @Richard Edited my question to include the config file sections. These didn't change after updating to the latest version of EF.